# adding elements inside specific location of associative array

Tags: javascript, associative-array

I was curious about adding elements in to an associative array using javascript,

```
var text=[{"key":"1", "value":"no"},{"key":"2", "value":"yes"} ];
```

what if I want to add an element in to above array... say to second location,

```
text[1].key="4";
text[1].value="test";
```

I ve tried it this way,

```
test.splice(parseInt(1), 0 );
test[1].type="4";
test[1].value="test";
```

Comment: What do you mean by "add a key" to the second location? Do you mean you want to insert into the array? In any case, you'd need to supply what you're splicing into the array. And parsing an integer into an integer is redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some example code (with which you can play around [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dPV83/20/)):

```
function toString(array) {
    var output = '';
    for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if(output != '')
            output += ' - ';
        output += array[i].key;
    }
    return output;
}

var array = [{"key":"1", "value":"no"},{"key":"2", "value":"yes"} ];

test = {"key":"4", "value":"test"};

alert(toString(array));
array.splice(1, 0, test);
alert(toString(array));
```

The `array.splice()` method takes the following parameters (taken from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp)):

```
array.splice(index,howmany,item1,.....,itemX)
```

- `index`: An integer that specifies at what position to add/remove items, Use negative values to specify the position from the end of the array.
- `howmany`: The number of items to be removed. If set to 0, no items will be removed.
- `itemN`: The new item(s) to be added to the array.

---

**EDIT**

To remove an element from the array you can use the same `splice` function in the following way:

```
array.splice(1, 1);
alert(toString(array));
```

Here we are indicating to `splice` at position `1`, remove `1` element but since we are not providing any elements to insert, none is inserted, which results in a single element at position `1` removed.

Comment: Just edited the answer to show the removal of an element as well (also updated the JSFiddle example). Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

To add an element onto the end of the array, you would use `.push()`.

```
text.push({key: 4, value: "no"});
```

To insert an item between the `[0]` and `[1]` items in the array, you can use `.splice()`

```
text.splice(1, 0, {key: 4, value: "no"});
```

Or, insert an empty object and then populate it:

```
text.splice(1, 0, {});
text[1].key = 4;
text[1].value = "no";
```

Comment: but this will not add the element to second location...I wanna add the element to a specific location..

Comment: @SamDaSilva - You left some confusion with the term "second location" as `[2]` would be the end of the array.  Anyway, I've added another option to my answer to insert an item into the middle of the array.